# Android - Payment Methods

Tags: android, payment

I have an application implemented and I want to sell certain items in it.
What alternatives payment methods can I use? And which is the most common way to sell items in Android for my app?
I want it to be as easy as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably best to create an in-app billing.

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html

Comment: When an item has been bought this way, it can be integrated into my app? Is there a good way to integrate the item?

Comment: in-app billing is only for digital items. You can't sell services or physical things with in-app billing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eBay for Android for selling items.
http://mobile.ebay.com/android/ebay-on-android

Comment: Will the user need an ebay account to buy my items?